# Explanation about this example on martingales

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

Given $(R_n)$ a sequence of independent random variables such that $P(R_n = -1) = P(R_n = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$, we want to show that $X_n := (R_1 + \ldots + R_n)^2 - n$ is indeed a martingale.

Now in the solution of this example, things go like

$$X_{n+1} = (R_1 + \ldots R_{n+1})^2 - (n+1)$$
hence we start with

$$
\begin{align}
X_{n+1} - X_n & = (R_1 + \ldots R_{n+1})^2 - (n+1) - (R_1 + \ldots + R_n)^2 - n
\\\\
& = (R_1 + \ldots R_n)^2 + R_{n+1}^2 - n - 1 - 2R_{n+1}(R_1 + \ldots + R_n) - (R_1 + \ldots + R_n)^2 - n
\\\\
& = 2R_{n+1}(R_1 + \ldots + R_n)
\end{align}
$$

Where he says $R_{n+1}^2 = 1$

I don't get why $R_{n+1}^2 = 1$ and also I don't get why the term $-n-n = -2n$ has vanished.

Then it goes on like ($H$ belongs to the filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$ to which the martingales are measurable)
$$\int_H (X_{n+1} - X_n)d\mathbb{P} = \int_H R_{n+1}\cdot 2\mathbb{1}_H(R_1 + \ldots R_n)d\mathbb{P}$$

Since $R_{n+1}$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}_n$ we get

$$ = \underbrace{\mathbb{E}[R_{n+1}]}_{=0}\int2\mathbb{1}_HR_{n+1} = \mathbb{E}[R_{n+1}]\cdot 2\mathbb{E}[H]\mathbb{E}[R_1 + \ldots R_n] = 0$$

I think there are some mistakes in this solution but I'm still a beginner in these topics so I'm asking you for clarifications about the whole exercise.

Thank you!

Comment: Notice that $P(R_n^2=1) = P(R_n=-1) + P(R_n=1)=1$ for all $n$. The phrase "$R_{n+1}^2=1$" has to be interpreted as "$R_{n+1}^2=1$ with probability 1". I hope this answers your first query. Regarding your second query, there is a small error in the expansion of $X_{n+1}-X_n$. The final $-n$ on the right hand side should be $+n$, in which case $R_{n+1}^2-n-1+n=1-1=0$. I hope this settles your second query.

Comment: @P.N.Karthik Thank you so much, it does indeed. So for the rest is all good?

Comment: @P.N.Karthik It would be a good idea to post that comment as a solution so that the question can be marked as answered.